# how to integrate hana cloud platform with AWS vora instance

Tags: vora

I am having access to HANA cloud platform and AWS Vora instance.  Is it possible to integrate them as we do the inpremise integration.

Answer (score 0):

Precondition is that the servers where Vora is located and where HANA is located can communicate with each other. If that is the case you can access HANA from Vora by using the HANA datasource. You can also access Vora from HANA by using the Spark Controller (separate installation; not included in current AWS developer edition).